# Laravel refers not to testing db but local one when running "RefreshDatabase" trait

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, phpunit

I am using docker and docker-compose. I already confirmed that Laravel properly referred to variables of `.env.testing` in `setUp()` method as shown below.

```
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        dd(env('APP_ENV'), env('DB_HOST'), env('DB_PORT'));
        parent::setUp();
    }
```

Result

```
"testing"
"db-testing"
"5432"
```

After `RefreshDatabase` trait had been executed, DB for the env `local` was refreshed instead of that for `testing`.

Am I missing somthing?

<docker-compose.yml>

```
version: "3.3"
volumes:
  php-fpm-socket:
  db-store:
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./infra/docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - php-fpm-socket:/var/run/php-fpm
      - ./backend:/work/backend

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./infra/docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - ${WEB_PORT:-80}:80
    volumes:
      - php-fpm-socket:/var/run/php-fpm
      - ./backend:/work/backend

  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: infra/docker/postgres/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db-store:/var/lib/postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: september_db

  db-testing:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: infra/docker/postgres/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: september_db
```

<infra/docker/postgres/Dockerfile>

```
FROM postgres:11-alpine

ENV TZ=UTC \
  POSTGRES_DB=september_db \
  POSTGRES_USER=admin \
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
```

<.env>

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=september_db
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=admin
```

<.env.testing>

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=testing
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=db-testing
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=september_db
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=admin
```

<phpunit.xml>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing" force="true"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4" force="true"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array" force="true"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="pgsql" force="true"/>
        <env name="DB_HOST" value="db-testing" force="true"/>
        <env name="DB_PORT" value="5432" force="true"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="september_db" force="true"/>
        <env name="DB_USERNAME" value="admin" force="true"/>
        <env name="DB_PASSWORD" value="admin" force="true"/>
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array" force="true"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync" force="true"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array" force="true"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false" force="true"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

All the services are up.

```
         Name                       Command               State           Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
september_app_1          docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up      9000/tcp
september_db-testing_1   docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp
september_db_1           docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
september_web_1          /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
```

Comment: Ain't you phpunit.xml wrong? <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="september_db" force="true"/> should that be september_db_testing or am i missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The same name “september_db” is used for both testing and local.

Comment: Everything looks okay. It is strange that it is not working... You can do some debbuging like `docker-compose stop db`, so you only have `db-testing` running, and see if the test throws any DB error. Also, if you are using Laravel 8, instead of using `<env ...` do `<server ...`. Also there is no need to double define the variables in `.env.testing` and `phpunit.xml` (`DB_HOST`, `DB_PORT`, and some others, see the oficial `phpunit.xml` in github). One last try would be to rename your service from `db-testing` to `db_testing` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Seems like nice ideas. Will try and share the result later! thank you :)

Comment: Couldnt it be a problem the db maps to the same port?

Comment: The two DBs are on a different container so there should be no problem if my understanding is correct. A port number on  a left hand side (host) should not be overlapped though.